# Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get() for attributes on my component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm getting an error with my custom lightning component. Seems like a common issue and can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to populate 2 picklists based on different fields in Cases. I'm getting the following error in my Javascript:

```
WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'options2' of component 'markup://ui:inputSelect {70:2;a} {reason}' is not visible to 'markup://c:CreateCaseV3 {3:2;a}'.
aura_proddebug.js:16507 

WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'options2' of component 'markup://ui:inputSelect {70:2;a} {reason}' is not visible to 'markup://c:CreateCaseV3 {3:2;a}'.
```

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="cases" type="Case[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute  name="options2" type="String[]"/>

<aura:attribute name="newCase" type="Case"
    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case', 
   'Subject': '',
   'Activity__c': '',
   'Reason': '',
   'Contact': '',
   'Description': '',
   'Origin' : '',
   'FOA__c' : '',
   'Project__c' : ''
   }"/>

   <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    Case Details <br/>

    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">

        <!-- Activity Field -->

         <div class="slds-form-element__control">    
            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="activity" label="Activity"
                class="slds-input"
                labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                value="{!v.newCase.Activity__c}"
                required="true"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Reason -->

        <div class="slds-form-element__control">    
            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="reason" label="Reason"
                class="slds-input"
                labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                value="{!v.newCase.Reason}"
                required="true"/>
        </div>
```

**Init function on the Controller**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    // Populate the picklist for Activity // 

    var populateactivities = component.get("c.getActivities");
    var inputsel = component.find("activity");
    var options = [];     

    options.push({"class" : "optionClass", label: "--None--", value: ""});

    populateactivities.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
            options.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
        }
        inputsel.set("v.options", options);

    });

    console.log(options)

    // Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(populateactivities);

    // Populate the picklist for Reasons
    var populatereasons = component.get("c.getReasons");
    var inputsel2 = component.find("reason");
    var options2 = [];     

    options2.push({"class" : "optionClass", label: "--None--", value: ""});

    populatereasons.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
            options2.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
        }   

        inputsel2.set("v.options2", options2);

    });

    console.log(options2);

    // Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(populatereasons);
```

Comment: This is locker-service. It won't allow you to make such change. Follow standard way if it could feasible to achieve.

Comment: There is no attribute called `options2` available in `<ui:inputSelect />`. So try replacing `inputsel2.set("v.options2", options2);` to `inputsel2.set("v.options", options2);`. Also there's nothing to do with locker-service here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute called `options2` available in `<ui:inputSelect />`.

So replacing `inputsel2.set("v.options2", options2);` to `inputsel2.set("v.options", options2);` would solve the issue.

For more info about ui:inputSelect can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm).